# JMeter web page test - Your session expired because of inactivity

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

There will be two actions once we click on log in button

1. login page action
2. dashboard action

Part of JMeter

1. login page action got success.in the continuation
2. dash board action got failed saying

   > "text":"Your session expired.","explanation":"Your session expired because of inactivity."

Can anyone help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) is likely to have some form of verification mechanism which checks user session by verifying parameter(s).

Well-behaved test should do exactly what real browser does, to wit:

1. Open login page
2. Perform login
3. Open dashboard

and your job is to ensure that requests which are being triggered by JMeter  are 100% match to the requests which are being sent by the real browser.

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, if your SUT checks the cookie - that should be enough. If not - most probably you  will need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) - the process of extracting dynamic parameters from previous response using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), saving them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replacing hard-coded (recorded) values with these variables.